# using array matches in filter query elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the data of this type in elastic search

```
    {
      "name":"John Doe",
       "age":"31",
       "state":"PA"
    
    
    },
    {
      "name":"John Doe",
       "age":"30",
       "state":"VA"
    
    
    },
    {
      "name":"John Doe",
       "age":"30",
       "state":"AZ"
    
    }
```

I wanted to find all John Doe's in the states of AZ and CA.

i have the below query

```
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                   {
                        "term": {
                             "name": "John Doe"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "state":["AZ,"CA"]
                        }
                    }
                    
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

this is showing me scoring in the results returned , also anyway to disable scoring by using filter and term condition like this

````
```
{
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": [
                   {
                        "term": {
                             "name": "John Doe"
                        }
                    }
                    
                ]
            }
        }
    }```
````

How do I query for the documents in elasticsearch with filter and array as in above

Answer (score 0):

[`filter` and `must`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clauses both work as a logical AND operator. The only difference is that in the `filter` clause the scoring is ignored, whereas in the `must` clause the matched documents contribute to the scoring.

You can either wrap your bool must query inside the filter clause, as shown below

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "name.keyword": "John Doe"
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "state.keyword": [
                  "AZ",
                  "CA"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can replace the `must` clause with the `filter` clause

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name.keyword": "John Doe"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "state.keyword": [
              "AZ",
              "CA"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Bunty did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you ;-)